# Oozie JA009 error on sub-action

Tags: oozie, oozie-workflow

I experience the following situation: I have created and launched an Oozie workflow comprising of two hive actions. Moments after the wf starts, the first action gets JA009 error and the wf is marked as SUSPENDED. Now the interesting part: the first action actually continues running and succeeds, although marked with the above error; in this moment the wf is stuck, not passing to the second action.

Any ideas on how to debug this?

Err msg:

> JA009: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for
>   mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.

Env info:

- Oozie 4.2.0.2.5.3.0-37
- Hadoop 2.7.3.2.5.3.0-37
- Hive 1.2.1000.2.5.3.0-37

Comment: Can you please post your `workflow.xml` file and the `error` here

Comment: @New_learner I have posted the error message. The workflow is trivial, containing two chained hive actions.